# How to detect if someone is the first to Facebook Like a page

Tags: javascript, facebook

I was wondering how I would go about detecting if when a person likes a post on my blog that they are first person to like it.

I tried this but it does not seem to work.

Any help/ideas?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
  // user clicked like
alert('Thank you for liking this post');
  var query = FB.Data.query('SELECT like_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="' + window.location + '"');

  query.wait(function(rows) {
    if ( ! rows[0].like_count ) {
       alert('Congrats - You are the first person to like this');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: <grammar-police>That should be "You're" not "Your"</grammar-police>

Comment: Not really sure because I have not worked with the Facebook API before. However, can you not have a callback function for the button OnClick and check if it was liked for the first time?

Comment: @sterex yes, that's the question. How do I detect the first time? I've no idea how to do that.

Comment: What problem are you having with that code? When the edge.create fires you shuold be able to check if the current count of likes is 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't want `function` in front of `FB.Event.subscribe()`.
2. Igy is right: You need to check for a Like count of 1, not 0, because the query is run after the Like has occurred.

The following should work, assuming you've called `FB.init()` before this, and your Like Button URL is the same as `window.location`.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
    // user clicked like
    alert('Thank you for liking this post');
    var query = FB.Data.query('SELECT like_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="' + window.location + '"');

    query.wait(function(rows) {
      if (rows[0].like_count == 1) {
        alert('Congrats - You are the first person to like this');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```